# Sql insert from users to comment

Tags: mysql, server

I have 2 table, user_table and comment_table that in comment_table i have foreign key to user_table which is user_id

Before someone can comment, it must be log in,

when someone log in and the they fill the comment form, they insert into comment_table right?

My question is, how to get the user_id from someone who logged in and then Insert into comment_table automatically?

Comment: What back-end language are you using? Considering you're using MySQL, I'll assume PHP, but the general concept applies to any language. If the user is logged in their ID should be stored into `$_SESSION`. Of course, you'll need to craft code to do that. From here it's just a matter of inserting `$_SESSION['id']` into the `comment` table.

Comment: Every server-side language should have some kind of session storage, you save the user ID there when they login, and use it when inserting into the DB.

Comment: Thanks to you guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, when the user logged in, you verified the username/password combination against the `user_table`, right?

If the verification was successful, you got the `ID` of the user, and you stored that `ID` in the web session. So, that's it! As long as the session hasn't expired, the `ID` is stored right there in the session. You get it from there and you use it in the insert.

Pretty easy.

Comment: Thanks everyone, finally i get it

Comment: If it's not too much to ask, apart from accepting the answer, can you upvote it?